# I can't see the textures behind a texture with alpha channel

Tags: android, opengl-es, transparency

I use 2D sprite texture applied to a square with transparent or semi-transparent area but I can't see anything through them (except the background) if there are other textures behind. I can see the background image because I use a transparent **GLSurfaceView**, the background is applied in a **ImageView** behind the **GLSurfaceView**.

**My problem in an image:**

[image]

Actually I use this code in the **onSurfaceCreated** method:

```
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
```

this in **onDrawFrame** method:

```
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        mObject1.draw(gl);
        mObject2.draw(gl);
```

and this in **draw** method of mObject1 and mObject2:

```
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glTranslatef((float) mPosition.getX(), (float) mPosition.getY(), 0f);

        float scaleFactor = (float) (2 * mRadius);
        gl.glScalef(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        gl.glColor4f (1f, 1.0f, 1, 1f);

        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

put

```
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```